# How to Handle Allow Location access alert of Firefox using selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, popup, alert

In Firefox i have set the location access to allow. but while automating the below popup is still shown. how to solve this?
I have used firefox options also.It's not working.
scenario: I have to select a city from the dropdown. Browser is showing alert
Allow location access to this site with two options .
1.Allow location,
2. Disallow

i have to click on "Allow location"

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: Provide some code, eventually some screenshot and/or html, tnx

Comment: final FirefoxOptions fireFoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
   fireFoxOptions.setHeadless(isHeadLess);
   final RemoteWebDriver firfoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver(fireFoxOptions);
   firfoxDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   firfoxDriver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1400, 800));
   domHelper = new DomHelper(firfoxDriver);
   return firfoxDriver;

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the notification popup as given below.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","./Resource/geckodriver.exe");
FirefoxProfile ffprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
ffprofile.setPreference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", false);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffprofile);
driver.get("https://jabong.com");
```